# how to do a while loop on python the define x1, x2, x3, etc

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

Hello I need to define a serie of data in python, like (x1=thing, x2=thing... to x100=thing) and I don't want to write all x(number). I tried with a loop like this

```
a=1
while(a<100):
    x'a'=thing
    a=a+1
```

but that doesn't work... 
How do I do a loop that returns me this:

```
x1=thing
x2=thing
x3=thing
x4=thing
etc...
```

I don't need to print it, only to have de x(number) defined.
thanks people

Comment: I'm sure you don't need so many variables. Store things in a list.

Comment: What you want is a list.

Comment: or if you want to access them by name, a dict. but it looks like you probably just need a list

Comment: Hmmm thank you! that was fast! but i'm doing an animation with matplotlib and when I use a list it shows several errors

Comment: Then post a question about your errors. Defining a hundred variables called `a1`...`a100` is not the solution to anything.

Answer (score 1):

You don't. That's not to say that you *can't*, but you DEFINITELY don't want to.

```
foo = []
for _ in range(100):  # do the following 100 times:
    foo.append("thing")
# or foo = ['thing' for _ in range(100)]
# or foo = ['thing'] * 100
```

This will give you a `list` named `foo` with the value `"thing"` in every element from 0 to 99.

```
foo[0]  # "thing"
foo[99] # "thing"
foo[100]  # throws an IndexError
```

The alternative would be to either directly manipulate the `globals` dict (which is a bad idea) or to play with `exec` (which is a VERY bad idea).

```
for num in range(1, 101):
    exec("x{} = 'thing'".format(num))
    # oh my God don't do this
```

```
for num in range(1, 101):
    globals()["x{}".format(num)] = "thing"
    # it's so ugly it burns!
```

That's not to say that `exec` is inherently bad, nor that directly manipulating the `globals` dict doesn't have its place. However if you're at the point of your education where you're still asking questions about Python on StackOverflow, you should not ever even ***consider*** using those approaches. At best it's an ugly hack where you should have done something else. At worst it will compromise your script and allow a malicious (or unwitting...read: yourself) user to do whatever it wants on your computer. That includes things like:

```
# WARNING, THIS CODE WILL TRASH YOUR COMPUTER
>>> exec(input("user input command> "))
user input command> import shutil; shutil.rmtree("C:/")
# DON'T COME CRYING TO ME WHEN YOUR SYSTEM WON'T BOOT
```

Comment: That is essentially `foo = 100*["thing"]`

Comment: @khelwood exactly so, though I somewhat doubted that OP actually just wants 100 elements of the exact same value....

Answer (score 0):

well thank you all!! turn out I didn't exactly knw how to use lists hahaha... this is what finally worked for me:

```
lina=[0,0]
linb=[0,0]
fig=plt.figure()
a=1
while(a<2):
   lina[a],=fig.add_subplot(111).plot(x,x, 'b^',markersize=20)
   linb[a],=fig.add_subplot(111).plot(x,x, 'rv',markersize=20)    
   a=a+1
```